# Enumeration in TensorFlow scope names

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having troubles understanding how does automatic enumeration work in scope naming. For example, the following:

```
with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
    with tf.variable_scope("bar") as scope:
         v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
```

would create a variable with *v.name* set to *foo/bar/v:0*.

If I reuse the variable, it would again be *foo/bar/v:0*. If I use another variable, it will be something else, e.g. *foo/bar/x:0*.

Could someone explain me the purpose of that enumerator *:0* and tell me what should I do to end up with a name like *foo/bar/x:1*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suffix `:0` indicates the index of the output argument of a Tensorflow operation. Under the hood, `get_variable` uses the `Variable` op, which has only one output. Therefore the suffix of any variable defined using `get_variable` can only be `:0`. Perhaps this can be clarified by example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

# First we instantiate a tensor using get_variable
v = tf.get_variable("v", [1])
print("operation used is {}".format(v.op.op_def.name))
print("The output tensor is named {}".format(v.name))
print()

# Now we instantiate two more tensors using split.
# We'll try to use the same name but Tensorflow will add the suffix "_1".
# Furthermore Tensorflow will use :[suffix] to indicate the index of the output.
v = tf.split(1, 2, tf.constant(np.random.randn(10, 4)), name='v')
print("length of v is {}".format(len(v)))
print("operation used is {}".format(v[0].op.op_def.name))
print("The first and second outputs are named {} and {} respectively".format(v[0].name, v[1].name))
```

The resulting output:

```
operation used is Variable
The output tensor is named v:0

length of v is 2
operation used is Split
The first and second outputs are named v_1:0 and v_1:1 respectively
```